# Find the range of a multivariate function with Sympy (Python)

Tags: python, function, range, sympy, bounds

I am having some troubles looking for several hours how to calculate the range of a multivariate function with sympy.

Let's say I would like to calculate the range of the following function f in sympy:

```
>>> x,y = symbols('x y')
>>> f = x*y
```

Plus, assume I know x€[0,1] and y€[-1,1].

**Does any method exist to get easily the range of f on account of x's and y's bounds ?**

Thank you !

PS : I know the method `function_range` already exists, but it looks like it works only for monovariate function.

An existing method implemented in sympy
A little program that could do what I want

Comment: I kindly ask you to add more information and examples to your discussion so that everyone can better help you. (Example: what did you try)

Comment: I tried to minimize the function consecutively beside each component. So minimize beside x first to get an expression with y and then minimize beside y. By doing the same process with maximization, I should have a upper and lower bound of the reachable values of f. However, when I minimize f beside x, I get Min(0,2*y). A clear solution is to take y = -1 but as Min(0,2*y) doesn't have critical point, sympy can't compute this minimum. Do you have any idea to fix this problem ? Or any idea to calculate the range of a multivariate function ? Thank you !

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.